# How to solve trig equation?

Tags: trigonometry

I know it must be really simple, but I really do need some help before exams, so, please:
I need to find $\sin x + \cos x$ if $\tan(x) = 4/3$ and $0<x<90$

Comment: LaTeX tip: Write `\sin x` and `\cos x` instead of `sin x` and `cos x`. It's the difference between $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, and $sin x$ and $cos x$. (The same works for other functions.)

Comment: Also, while the `\tg x` option is unavailable, you can write `\operatorname{tg} x`. Alternatively, just write `\tan x`.

Comment: Will do. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with right-angle triangles in Quadrant I ($0<x<90$ degrees):

$$
sin(\theta) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}\\
cos(\theta) = \frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}\\
tan(\theta) = \frac{opposite}{adjacent}
$$

(The SOHCAHTOA mnemonic may be of help here.)

From your question:

$$ tg(x) = tan(x) = \frac{4}{3} = \frac{opposite}{adjacent} $$

Therefore:

$$
opposite = 4\\
adjacent = 3
$$

Ergo, on a right-angle triangle, the side opposite the angle $x$ has length 4 and the side adjacent to the angle $x$ has length 3. From the pythagorean theorem:

$$ hypotenuse^2 = adjacent^2 + opposite^2\\
c^2 = a^2+b^2 = 3^2+4^2 = 9+16 = 25\\
c = hypotenuse = \sqrt{25} = 5$$

The right-angle triangle you have here is, as shown, a 3-4-5 triangle. Now that we have the length of all of the sides, the following trigonometric identities for your triangle are complete.

$$
sin(x) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse} = \frac{4}{5}\\
cos(x) = \frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse} = \frac{3}{5}\\
tan(x) = \frac{opposite}{adjacent} = \frac{4}{3}
$$

Therefore:

$$
sin(x)+cos(x) = \frac{4}{5}+\frac{3}{5} = \frac{7}{5}
$$

Comment: Just wondering, but why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Just draw a right angled triangle with opposite side 4 and adjacent side 3. Then use Pythagoras to get the hypotenuse. Then you can get $ sinx$ and $\ cosx$